# from_buffer_copy undefined in derived class

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a python class that looks like the following:

```
class buf(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [
                ("data", ctypes.c_void_p),
                ("size", ctypes.c_uint32),
                ]
```

I want to store a python buffer inside of it. I was told to use: from_buffer_copy. If I do `mystruct.from_buffer_copy(mybuffer)` I get

> mystruct object has no attribute from_buffer_copy

Though

`ctypes.Structure.from_buffer_copy(mybuffer)` calls the function but crashes because the class is not instantiated. How come my class cant access the base class from_buffer_copy? I have tried using super to call it but that failed as well. Any idea what the from_buffer_copy method is not accessible on my inherited struct?

Thanks.

Alternative ways to get a buffer interface into that structure are also appreciated.

Comment: `from_buffer_copy` is defined by the metaclass, `type(ctypes.Structure)`. You cannot access this method from an instance of the class. Use `buf.from_buffer_copy(mybuffer)` to construct an instance of `buf` from a copy of the data in `mybuffer`.

Comment: That worked! I definitely misunderstood how it was meant to be used. Mark it as a answer and I will accept it.